# How to solve the numerical instability to a solution of a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations, approximation, runge-kutta

I have been trying to get the numerical solution to the following system of ordinary differential equations:

Equations for the movement of a body through air in a inclined lunch:
(apparently LaTeX doesn't work on stack overflow)

---

```
u'= -F(u, theta, t)*cos(theta)
v'= -F(v, theta, t)*sin(theta)-mg
```

---

by the Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg Algorithm, but in the middle of the computation i have to calculate theta, that is calculated by

```
arccos(u/sqrt(u^2+v^2)) or arcsin(v/sqrt(u^2+v^2)),
```

but eventually `theta` gets too small and I need it to solve the function `F( v, theta, t)` and to find the value `V = sqrt(v^2 + u^2)` I use `V = (v/sin(theta))`, but as `theta` gets small so does `sin(theta)` and I get a numerical error from a given iteration forward `-1.IND00`, It is problably because `theta` is too small, i tried to make `theta` go from a small positive angle like `0.00001` to a small negative angle like `-0.00001` (`if(fabs(theta)<0.00001) theta = -0.00001`) but it seems that `theta` gets trapped into this negative value, does anyone have an indication on what to do to resolve this numerical instability ?

Comment: Unless you can explain the technical challenge related to this question in more concrete terms, you might get better results from https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought of that, but since this is a problem specifically of numerical instability I imagine stack overflow is best suited for this problem, i don't know if there are many people in math.stackexchange that do numerical methods problems

Comment: Why don't you try to approximate V with cos(theta). Where I see the problem is that when theta -> 0, sin(theta) -> theta -> 0, and dividing when the denominator tends to zero, that's where the problem comes for. Also you could try to approximate theta with the tangent function and avoid the problems for small angles

Comment: What exactly is `F(a,b,c)` and how do you determine inside this function if `a` comes from the value of `u` or from the value of `v`? Would it not be easier to write `u'=-f(u,v)*u; v'=-f(u,v)*v-g`? Note that the mass divides out of `m*y''=m*v'=force_y=-c(u,v)*v-m*g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use the inverse cosine or sine functions to determine the angle of a point. To get

```
theta = arg ( u + i*v)
```

use

```
theta = atan2(v,u).
```

This still has the problem that it jumps on the negative half axis, that is for `v=0, u<0`. That can be solved by making `theta` a third dynamical variable, so that

```
 theta' = Im( (u'+i*v')/(u+i*v) ) = (u*v' - u'*v) / (u^2+v^2)
```

---

But really, the equation for the free fall with air friction is easiest implemented as

```
def friction(vx, vy):
    v = hypot(vx, vy)
    return k*v

def freefall_ode(t, u):
    rx, ry, vx, vy = u
    f=friction(vx, vy)
    ax = -f*vx
    ay = -f*vy - g
    return array([ vx, vy, ax, ay ])
```

so that you do not need any angle or to try to weaken the coupling of the velocity components by reducing it to the angle of the velocity vector. This you can now plug into the integration method of your choice, applied as a method for vector-valued systems.